# Spring Webflux: Nested Flatmap alternative

Tags: java, kotlin, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a scenario where second mono depended on firstMono and ThridMono call  Dependeded on second mono out.

I written the code as below.

```
  firstMono.flatMap{

    val secondMono = callWebservice(firstMono)

    val thrirdMono = secondMono.flatMap { secondMonoResponse ->
        if (secondMonoResponse.getName.equals("ABC")) {
            callAnotherWebService(secondMon)
        } else {
            secondMono
        }
    }
}
```

How can I avoid the second flatMap here?.Is there a way I can do this without nested flatMap.I should be calling thrirdMono only condition met.

Answer (score 1):

The answer may vary depending on what exactly does each Mono perform.
Nevertheless, when I look on the snippet, I don't see the point of invoking `flatMap{}` on the firstMono, so it could probably look, as follows:

```
callWebservice(firstMono)
  .flatMap { secondMonoResponse ->
    if (secondMonoResponse.name == "ABC" ) {
      callAnotherWebService(secondMono)
    } else {
      secondMono
    }
  }
```

On the other hand, a .zip method could be used here, as well:

```
val secondMono = callWebservice(firstMono)
Mono.zip(firstMono, callWebservice(firstMono))
  .flatMap { 
    val secondMonoResponse = it.t2
    if (secondMonoResponse.name == "ABC" ) {
      callAnotherWebService(secondMono)
    } else {
      secondMono
    }
  }
```

**Note**: I've removed `val thrirdMono`, because the above code snippet won't compile as the return type is Unit (instead of the Mono).